How does Ruby the String interpolation of a String object?
Is my assumption correct that Ruby does not call the to_s or to_str method when interpreting a String object during string-interpolation?
a = "Hallo"
class String
  def to_s
    "Servus"
  end
end
def a.to_s
  "Servus"
end
puts "Hier sagt man #{a}"

=> Hier sagt man Hallo
Is it more efficient to check if an object is a String than to simply call the to_s method?

It's more efficient because you already know that a string is a string, i.e. you can interpolate it straightaway. Calling to_s would require an additional check for the method's return value as it might return a non-string value. Also, where would you stop? Would you call to_s on the return value?

That makes sense, thank you!


Is my assumption correct that Ruby does not call the to_s or to_str method when interpreting a String object during string-interpolation?

It is correct.
The test you provided doesn't rule out the possibility that the parser took a shortcut by recognizing that a was assigned to a string literal. Here's a test that does:
a = "Hallo"
class String
  def to_s
    "Servus"
  end
end
def a.to_s
  "Servus"
end

test_string = 'puts "Hier sagt man #{' + 97.chr + '}'

eval(test_string) # => Hier sagt man Hallo

Now, Ruby doesn't actually do any kind of "local variable is a literal string" automatic substitution, because Ruby is so dynamic that the value of a could be updated in any of the following lines of code without the parser knowing. But if you didn't already know for sure that that's the case, a test like the above guarantees it.


Is it more efficient to check if an object is a String than to simply call the to_s method?

Here's another interesting test, which shows that Ruby (at least C Ruby) isn't using some secret shortcut to check if it's exactly a String, but is rather using something more like is_a?:
class Foo < String
  def to_s
    "foo"
  end

  def to_str
    "foo"
  end
end

a = Foo.new("initial value")

puts "a: #{a}"

#=> a: initial value

If we had seen a: foo instead, we would know that a very simple (and presumably more efficient) check was used, and was unable to recognize that the Foo object was an instance of a String subclass.
Given the above, we've ruled out the possibility that the test for String is a simple test optimized for exactly String classes. Without examining the code in every Ruby implementation, there a few other things we know for sure:

Ruby method lookups are a source of inefficiency.
It only takes a single is_a? method call to identify whether an object is an instance of a String subclass.
Ruby implementations vary, but C Ruby at least may not even have to do a method lookup for is_a?, because it can just use rb_obj_is_kind_of for any object type.
Checking for to_s and to_str causes at least 1 or 2 method lookups. Actually calling them causes an unknown number of method lookups and additional calls.
As noted in other comments, there's no guarantee that to_s or to_str actually returns a string, so the is_a? check has to be repeated.

Considering these things, we can say that it's at least twice as efficient to check if the object is a String as to call to_s or to_str without checking first, and on average it's likely much more efficient.

Thank you for the examples, that makes things clear.

A test can only prove or disprove the behavior of one specific version of one specific Ruby implementation running one specific piece of code. In other words, the fact that the code in your question behaves in a particular way when run on version 3.3.5 of YARV does not automatically guarantee that it will behave the same way in a different piece of code, or on a different version of YARV, or on a different Ruby implementation such as TruffleRuby, JRuby, MRuby, or Opal.
If you want to know about the behavior of Ruby as opposed to the behavior of one specific version of one specific implementation, then you cannot get that answer through testing. You have to look at the specification.
Unfortunately, the Ruby Programming Language does not have a single, unified, specification document like, for example, ECMAScript has.
There are several resources, the sum of which can be considered kind of a specification for the Ruby programming language.
Some of these resources are:

The ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby specification – Note that the ISO Ruby Specification was written around 2009–2010 with the specific goal that all existing Ruby implementations at the time would easily be compliant. Since YARV and MacRuby only implement Ruby 1.9+ and MRI only implements Ruby 1.8 and lower and JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, and IronRuby (at the time) only implemented a subset of Ruby 1.8, this means that the ISO Ruby Specification only contains features that are common to both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. Also, the ISO Ruby Specification was specifically intended to be minimal and only contain the features that are absolutely required for writing Ruby programs. Because of that, it does for example only specify Strings very broadly (since they have changed significantly between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9). It obviously also does not specify features which were added after the ISO Ruby Specification was written, such as Ractors or Pattern Matching.
The Ruby Spec Suite aka ruby/spec – Note that the ruby/spec is unfortunately far from complete. However, I quite like it because it is written in Ruby instead of "ISO-standardese", which is much easier to read for a Rubyist, and it doubles as an executable conformance test suite.
The Ruby Programming Language by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto – This book was written by David Flanagan together with Ruby's creator matz to serve as a Language Reference for Ruby.
Programming Ruby by Noel Rappin, with Dave Thomas – This book was the first English book about Ruby and served as the standard introduction and description of Ruby for a long time. This book also first documented the Ruby core library and standard library, and the authors donated that documentation back to the community.
The Ruby Issue Tracking System, specifically, the Feature sub-tracker – However, please note that unfortunately, the community is really, really bad at distinguishing between Tickets about the Ruby Programming Language and Tickets about the YARV Ruby Implementation: they both get intermingled in the tracker.
The Meeting Logs of the Ruby Developer Meetings. (Same problem: Ruby and YARV get intermingled.)
New features are often discussed on the mailing lists, in particular the ruby-core (English) and ruby-dev (Japanese) mailing lists. (Same problem again.)
The Ruby documentation – Again, be aware that this documentation is generated from the source code of YARV and does not distinguish between features of Ruby and features of YARV.
In the past, there were a couple of attempts of formalizing changes to the Ruby Specification, such as the Ruby Change Request (RCR) and Ruby Enhancement Proposal (REP) processes, both of which were unsuccessful.
If all else fails, you need to check the source code of the popular Ruby implementations to see what they actually do. Please note the plural: you have to look at multiple, ideally all, implementations to figure out what the consensus is. Only looking at one implementation cannot possibly tell you whether what you are looking at is an implementation quirk of this particular implementation or is a universally agreed-upon behavior of the Ruby Language.

Let's look at the ISO Ruby Programming Language Specification first. Section 8.7.6.3.3 Double quoted strings has the answers we need. Under the sub-heading Semantics, it describes how expressions are interpolated into double quoted strings [note that I reformatted that quote to fit within the limitations of Stack Overflow Markdown – for example, the original uses an alphabetical list which Stack Overflow Markdown does not support, so I converted it to a numbered list]:

An interpolated-character-sequence is evaluated as follows:

If it is of the form # global-variable-identifier, evaluate the global-variable-identifier (see 11.5.4.4). Let V be the resulting value.
If it is of the form # class-variable-identifier, evaluate the class-variable-identifier (see 11.5.4.5). Let V be the resulting value.
If it is of the form # instance-variable-identifier, evaluate the instance-variable-identifier (see 11.5.4.6). Let V be the resulting value.
If it is of the form # { compound-statement }, evaluate the compound-statement (see 10.2). Let V be the resulting value.
If V is an instance of the class String, the value of interpolated-character-sequence is V.
Otherwise, invoke the method to_s on V with no arguments. Let S be the resulting value.
If S is an instance of the class String, the value of interpolated-character-sequence is S.
Otherwise, the behavior is unspecified.


Clauses #1–4 just describe the different kinds of Ruby code that can be interpolated:

Global variables: "Hello, #$world"
Class hierarchy variables: "Hello, #@@world"
Instance variables: "Hello, #@world"
Arbitrarily complex Ruby expressions: "Hello, #{some.long(:complex, :expression); with.many(:parts)}"

But in the end, in all of those four cases, the expression evaluates to some value V. For this question, we are interested in what happens to V. The first clause that talks about what happens to V is clause #5:

If V is an instance of the class String, the value of interpolated-character-sequence is V.

What this says is, if whatever we are interpolating into the string already is a string, we just use it directly. There are some intricacies here, though: what does it mean to be "an instance of the class String? For this, we have to look at a different part of the specification.
Section 6.5.2 Classes defines the term direct instance:

A class is itself an object, and creates other objects. The created objects are called direct instances of the class (see 13.2.4).

And section 6.5.4 Inheritance defines the term instance:

If an object C is a direct instance of a class D, C is called an
instance of D and all its superclasses.

So, "an instance of the class String" means an object that was created by instantiating the class String or any subclass of String.
So, what happens if the result of evaluating the interpolated Ruby code is not an instance of the class String? That's where clause #6 comes in:

Otherwise, invoke the method to_s on V with no arguments. Let S be the resulting value.

So, if the value we are trying to interpolate into the string is not already a string, we are allowing it to represent itself as a string by sending it the message to_s with no arguments. The return value of that message send is now a (potentially) different value S.
Clause #7 finally tells us what the result of the string interpolation is:

If S is an instance of the class String, the value of interpolated-character-sequence is S.

But, you notice, it contains another sanity check: it does not blindly assume that the return value of to_s is an instance of String. There is again another check that S is an instance of the class String.
IFF S is an instance of the class String, THEN it is used as the string to interpolate into the enclosing string. However, what happens if it is not an instance of the class String? That's where clause #8 comes in, which gives the ultimate, if a bit disappointing answer "We don't know":

Otherwise, the behavior is unspecified.

Which tells us … nothing, really. If to_s does not return an instance of the class String, then the specification does not say what happens during string interpolation. But at least, it tells us one thing: whatever we think it does, we cannot rely on that. Whatever happens in our tests, we cannot rely on that. Whatever one Ruby implementation does, we cannot rely on that.
Unless, that is, we get another guarantee from a different source. For example, if we know with 100% absolute certainty that our code will only be executed on JRuby, and the JRuby documentation contains a guarantee that a certain thing will always happen, then we can rely on that thing to happen. But if we don't have such a guarantee, then anything could happen: the implementation could try to re-send to_s as many times as it takes until it returns an instance of the class String, it could crash, it could format the disk, or it could launch the proverbial nukes.
However, as I mentioned above, there are multiple different places where the behavior of Ruby is documented, so, it is still possible that a different place says something different / more precise. One place that I personally like to look, is the Ruby Spec Suite aka ruby/spec. And, indeed, it actually has something interesting to say:

it "uses an internal representation when #to_s doesn't return a String" do
  obj = mock('to_s')
  obj.stub!(:to_s).and_return(42)

  # See rubyspec commit 787c132d by yugui. There is value in
  # ensuring that this behavior works. So rather than removing
  # this spec completely, the only thing that can be asserted
  # is that if you interpolate an object that fails to return
  # a String, you will still get a String and not raise an
  # exception.
  "#{obj}".should be_an_instance_of(String)
end


As you can see, the Ruby Spec Suite actually guarantees that, if to_s does not return an instance of the class String, the Ruby implementation will instead use some (unspecified) internal representation, but will not raise an exception. This is a stricter guarantee than the ISO Ruby Language Specification which does not give any guarantee at all. We still don't know what the resulting string will be, but at least we know that there will be a resulting string.
It is actually investing to look at the history of that specification a bit. The example was added in commit 2f221d11b8986f49a020da63e24e05086d377f0d like so:

it "interpolates the return value of Object#inspect if Object#to_s does not return a String instance" do
  object = Object.new
  inspect_string = object.inspect
  def object.to_s; 42; end
  "#{object}".should == inspect_string
end


As you can see, this gives a very strong guarantee, namely, that inspect will be used if to_s does not return an instance of the class String.
However, this was later both softened and strengthened several times [I'm leaving out some intermediate steps]. In commit 787c132d, it was relaxed to only guarantee that it doesn't raise an exception and the result is not empty:

it "interpolates an implementation depended representation of an object if the object does not return a String for #to_s and the representation of the object is not empty" do 
  obj = mock('to_s')
  obj.stub!(:to_s).and_return(42)

  s = nil
  lambda { s = "#{obj}" }.should_not raise_error
  s.should_not be_empty
end


So, this only guarantees that it will not raise an exception and that the result is not empty, whereas before, it guaranteed that inspect would be called and the result of inspect would be the string that is interpolated into the surrounding string.
Commit e4a347df819b532bb109aed0d6a4944499502305 then finally brings it into the form we have seen above, where it guarantees that the result is, in fact, an instance of the class String.
Which brings us back to your question(s):

Is my assumption correct that Ruby does not call the to_s or to_str method when interpreting a String object during string-interpolation?

Yes, that assumption is correct. Moreover, it is now no longer an assumption: we have seen that both the ISO Ruby Language Specification and the Ruby Spec Suite guarantee it. The Ruby Spec Suite is particularly important in this regard, because all mainstream Ruby implementations run the Ruby Spec Suite as part of their release process, so you can guarantee that they are all compliant with it – or at least that they explicitly list out the incompatibilities like Opal does here or TruffleRuby does here.

Is it more efficient to check if an object is a String than to simply call the to_s method?

That's not really answerable. It would depend highly on the specific Ruby implementation being used, the specific benchmark being run, etc. It is hard to imagine a real-world implementation were it would not be true, but it would be easy to construct a contrived counterexample: just insert an arbitrary delay into class lookup.

How does Ruby the String interpolation of a String object?

Well, that's the middle two pages of this giant answer :-D
I hope that this answer helps you to understand where and how you can find such things out yourself, and do so in a general way that is guaranteed to be correct across a wide variety of Ruby implementations.
